# When running rails server as daemon, why do I need to enable eager_load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, associations, daemon, eager-loading

When I run `rails s -d`, if I don't set `config.eager_load` to `true`, then the following code gives error:

```
Plan.includes(
  [{template: [
               {phases: {sections: {questions: :answers}}}
              ]},
   {plans_guidance_groups: {guidance_group: :guidances}}
  ]).find(id)
```

Note:

- Template has many plan, plan belongs to template
- Template has many phases, phase belongs to template

And also the error I get is:

```
Association named 'phases' was not found on Template; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

But the error doesn't make sense since the association has indeed been defined:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base

  # more code here

  ##
  # Associations
  belongs_to :org
  has_many :plans
  has_many :phases, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sections, through: :phases
  has_many :questions, through: :sections

  # more code here
```

When I run `rails s -d`, if I set `config.eager_load` to `true`, it works fine.

Also, when I run `rails s` with `config.eager_load` to `false`, it works fine, so I suspect there is something wrong about the daemon. But I don't know what it is, and I don't know where to look for. Does anyone know what's going on and where to find its documentation?

Comment: Is `Phase` defined in `app/model/phase.rb`? I'm guessing it's an autoloading error. Assuming you've named everything correctly, [autoloading should work](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Comment: If I run the rails server in normal non-daemon mode, everything works fine, so everything is named correctly

Comment: @HenryYang Try Plan.eager_load  instead of Plan.includes

Comment: which version of rails?

Comment: rails version = 4.2.10

Comment: @NeverBe I tried replacing .includes with .eager_load, but the server daemon hang in there when it reaches that part of code

Comment: I have updated the question with more information